# Nvidia 331 on kernel 3.18.1

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, 14.10, bumblebee

ThinkPad t540p, running Ubuntu 14.10 and kernel 3.18.1. Trying to install bumblebee and as I understand it get nvidia-331 to work...

Installing nvidia-331 yields an error and dpkg-reconfigure does the same:

```
sindri@sindri-tp:~$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure nvidia-331
Removing all DKMS Modules
Done.
INFO:Enable nvidia-331
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/dell_latitude
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/lenovo_thinkpad
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/put_your_quirks_here
Loading new nvidia-331-331.113 DKMS files...
Building only for 3.18.1-031801-lowlatency
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 3.18.1-031801-lowlatency
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-3.18.1-031801-lowlatency is not     supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.18.1-031801-lowlatency (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia-331/331.113/build/make.log for more information.
```

Kernel package is not supported?

```
sindri@sindri-tp:/usr/src/nvidia-331-331.113$ uname -a
Linux sindri-tp 3.18.1-031801-lowlatency #201412170637 SMP PREEMPT Wed Dec 17 11:46:57 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I have been back and forth, trying to use xorg-edgers's ppa, driver downloaded from the nvidia website, but I always get some error when building the DKMS module.

**Update #1**

Tried installing nvidia-340 and that seemed to work well, at least I got no errors. Restarting however only showed blank screen so I had to revert to nvidia-current.

**Update #2**

Grabbed the Xorg.8.log after I got blank screen. These are the contents:

```
sindri@sindri-tp:~$ grep EE Xorg.8.log 
[ 61517.833] Current Operating System: Linux sindri-tp 3.18.1-031801-lowlatency #201412170637 SMP PREEMPT Wed Dec 17 11:46:57 UTC 2014 x86_64
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[ 61517.861] (EE) Failed to load module "kbd" (module does not exist, 0)
[ 61517.861] (EE) No devices detected.
[ 61517.866] (EE) Failed to load module "kbd" (module does not exist, 0)
[ 61520.061] (EE) intel(0): [drm] failed to set drm interface version: Permission denied [13].
[ 61520.061] (EE) intel(0): Failed to claim DRM device.
[ 61520.061] (EE) Screen(s) found, but none have a usable configuration.
[ 61520.061] (EE) 
[ 61520.061] (EE) no screens found(EE) 
[ 61520.061] (EE) 
[ 61520.061] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.8.log" for additional information.
[ 61520.061] (EE) 
[ 61520.061] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after trying a number of things I installed the 3.17 kernel. I purged xorg-edgers and installed nvidia-331 from apt-get and I now have a working setup.

I ran into two problems, the first was that I could not change the resolution on my laptop monitor from 640x320. Deleting `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` resolved that. The second was that when I logged in, unity crashed. Deleting `~/.config/dconf/user` reset all my settings but unity worked as it should.